# How to convert BLOB to image using python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, blob

I need to send an image from client to server using blob

I have converted a image to `BLOB` in jquery (client side) and sending the blob to python flask (server side) the problem is, I can't recreate image from `BLOB`. I have tried the following code in python but failed to get the image

Jquery code to convert image to blob:

```
function changeFile() {
     var file = this.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener('load', readFile);
     reader.readAsText(file);
}

function readFile(event) {
     document.body.textContent = event.target.result;
     console.log(event.target.result);
     appendFileAndSubmit(event.target.result);
}


function appendFileAndSubmit(imageUrl){
     var ImageURL = imageUrl
     var data = {
          'logo':ImageURL
          }
             $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://sdsdss/User/imgBlob',
                        method: 'POST',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }).done(function(response){    
                        var datas = JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log(datas);
                    });
                }
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", changeFile);
```

Python Code: To recreate `BLOB` to image

```
function getImage(self):
     reqData = json.loads(request.data)
     Logo = reqData['logo']
     png_recovered = base64.decodestring(Logo)
     f = open("temp.png", "w")
     f.write(png_recovered)
     f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't read the file as text, You are dealing with binary data.
    Best way to transfer binary with json is if you read the file as base64 instead `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` This will encode all bytes to a web safe base64 string (no slash or plus). Then you have to decode it with python as well.
2. I discourage you from using json when dealing with file transfer as it will increase the bandwidth with ~3 times as much (not to mention the time it also takes to decode and encode it back and forth) For this I recommend you instead use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append('logo', files[0])

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://sdsdss/User/imgBlob',
  method: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  // Setting false prevent jQuery from transforming the data
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(response))
})
```

or simpler yet, just post the file without any formdata, json or extra fields if they are not necessary.

```
fetch(uploudUrl, { method 'PUT', body: this.files[0] })
```

Comment: actually am sending image to api so json is the general structure am following for all the clients i can't write form data for this particular image..i will try with base64 string